# How to concat strings with space delimiter where each string is nullable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, string-concatenation, null-coalescing

I have a table with multiple nullable string fields.

For reporting I would like to combine them into a single string that is delimited with a space for every field. The right side must be trimmed.

Test data:

```
DECLARE
  @test 
TABLE
(
    f1 NVARCHAR(100)
  , f2 NVARCHAR(100)
  , f3 NVARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @test 
-- NULL values must be skipped
      SELECT NULL       , NULL , NULL
UNION SELECT NULL       , NULL , 'foo'
UNION SELECT NULL       , 'foo', NULL
UNION SELECT 'foo'      , NULL , NULL
UNION SELECT NULL       , 'foo', 'bar'
UNION SELECT 'foo'      , 'bar', NULL
UNION SELECT 'foo'      , NULL , 'bar'
UNION SELECT 'foo'      , 'bar', 'baz'
-- Empty string values must be skipped
UNION SELECT 'foo'      , ''   , 'bar'
UNION SELECT ''         , ''   , 'baz' 
-- Spaces in values must be kept
UNION SELECT 'foo   bar', ''   , 'baz'
-- The table should not contain values with surrounding space
-- So this case is not important
UNION SELECT ' foo '    , ' '  , 'baz '
```

The expected results:

```
''
'foo'
'foo'
'foo'
'foo bar'
'foo bar'
'foo bar'
'foo bar baz'
'foo bar'
'baz'
'foo   bar baz'
'foo  baz'
' foo   baz' -- This is optional
```

My current code:

```
SELECT
  RTRIM(
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(f1, '') = '' THEN '' ELSE f1 + ' ' END
  + CASE WHEN ISNULL(f2, '') = '' THEN '' ELSE f2 + ' ' END
  + CASE WHEN ISNULL(f3, '') = '' THEN '' ELSE f3 + ' ' END
  )
FROM
  @test
```

This works, but I was wondering if there is a less verbose way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012, there is a CONCAT function. 
You can use the following as well:

```
SELECT
  RTRIM(CONCAT(  
      NULLIF(f1, '') + ' '
    , NULLIF(f2, '') + ' '
    , NULLIF(f3, '') + ' '
  ))
FROM
  @test
```

Comment: In your answer where is the advantage over just using `+` instead of `CONCAT()`?

Comment: `CONCAT()` does automatic `ISNULL` according to the docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh231515.aspx

Comment: I fixed your answer and this is indeed shorter than the answer of @podiluska

Answer (score 1):

Because `null` + a space is still `null`, you can use

```
select 
    isnull(nullif(f1,'')+' ','') + 
    isnull(nullif(f2,'')+' ','') + 
    isnull(nullif(f3,'')+' ','') 
from @test
```

Comment: Will not work for the `'', '', 'bar'` case. The result contains leading spaces.

Comment: You could add a `NULLIF(f1, '')`, etc. in there though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, so easy after podiluska's answer.

```
select 
    LTRIM(RTRIM(isnull(f1+' ','') + 
    isnull(f2+' ','') + 
    isnull(f3+' ','') ))
from @test
```